# How to open a new Window of the Sonoma web apps from the command line?

Tags: web-application, macos-sonoma

## What I want to do

I added chatGPT as a web app to my dock. I now want to open a new instance of chatGPT using SKHD. Therefore I need to configure a shortcut in skhdrc.

## What I tried

Since the web apps live in your Applications folder, I tried to use `open ChatGPT.app -n`, but this opened a duplicate instance of every instance of the app that is currently open. Meaning: If I have 2 instances open named A and B, I now have 2xA and 2xB when invoking `open ChatGPT.app -n`.

## Steps to reproduce

1. add chat.openai.com as Sonoma web app to your dock
2. Open 2 instances of it, as in two unique chats either new of from your history
3. Invoke `open ChatGPT.app -n` in terminal
4. You now should have 4 windows and no new windows, but copies of the chats that where already open